# Change CSS class from a Div On a click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The last week I'm stuck at a problem. I looked al over the internet and I tought I found the solution dozens of times, but all did not seem to work. What I want is the following: **When I click on element A I want the class of element B being changed**

My codes:

**Html:**

```
<div class="header"> 

    <a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>

    <nav class="navigation_menu id="nav">

            <ul class="navigation_ul">

                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="exclude_under_line"><a href="#">Portfolio<span class="drop_arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Trimester 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trimester 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trimester 3</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>

            </ul>

    </nav>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/** General Style **/

body {
    background:f5f5f5;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/** Text Style **/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

/** Header Style **/

.header {
    background: #607d8b;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

/** Navigation Menu **/

    /** Basic Style **/

    .navigation_menu > a { 
        display: none; /* Removes Show Navigation and Hide Navigation */
     }

     .navigation_menu ul{
        margin: 0px; /* Removes the auto create margin around the ul element */
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .navigation_menu li { 
        position: relative; /* Makes Drop Down Menu Work and being showed */
        list-style-type: none; /* Removes dots before Li elements  */
        font-size:18px; /* Makes font size 18 */
    }

    .navigation_menu > ul > li {
        height: 30px; /* Determines The width height between drop down and menu */
        float: left; /* Makes them float besides each other */
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    .navigation_menu > ul > li > ul {
        padding: 0px; /* Removes the automatic created padding around the drop down ul */
        width: 140%; /* Makes the text in drop down menu (whos bigger then parent) not go to a second line */
        margin-top: -4px; /* Pushes the drop down are go down 8 pixels */
        position: absolute; /*Makes the child ul not affect the parent li */
    }

    .navigation_menu li ul {
        display: none;  /* Hides Drop Down */
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .navigation_menu li:hover ul {
         display: block; /* Makes Drop Down Menu Work again */
         background: white;
         box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    /** Drop Arrow Style **/

    .drop_arrow {
        font-size:12px; /* Edits the size of the drop arrow */
        margin-left:4px; /* Moves it a little bit away from the text next to it */
        line-height:0%; /* Makes the icon don't affect the word next to it */
    }

    /* Hamburger  Style */

    .nav-toggle {
        display:none;
    }

    .nav-toggle { cursor: pointer; padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px; }

    .nav-toggle span, .nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after {
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 1px;
      height: 3px;
      width: 20px;
      background: white;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
    }

    .nav-toggle span:before {
      top: -7px; 
    }

    .nav-toggle span:after {
      bottom: -7px;
    }

    .nav-toggle span, .nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after {
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-toggle.active span {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-toggle.active span:before, .nav-toggle.active span:after {
      top: 0;
    }

    .nav-toggle.active span:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .nav-toggle.active span:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    @media only screen and ( max-width: 400px )  {

        .nav-toggle {
            display:block;
        }

        .navigation_menu {
            display: none;
        }

        .navigation_menu_new {
             display: block;
        }

    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.querySelector( ".nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  });
```

So what I basicly want is that when I click on the "Nav-Toggle" div I want that the class of "navigation_menu" (when the screen size is below 400) change from .navigation_menu to .navigation_menu_new. I want this so the menu will go from invisble to visible after the visiter clicks on the hamburger.

Here is the pen from codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXVjrv

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding a click event listener onto the `.nav-toggle` element, and in that listener, you are using `this` to call the `classList.toggle` which is the `nav-toggle` element. Shouldn't you be calling that on the element you want to change the class of?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: You tagged jQuery on this question. Was that intentional?

Comment: Also, your only `.nav-toggle` element only contains an empty span in your html, so what exactly are you clicking on when you are testing this?

Comment: There is a typo in your html `class="navigation_menu id="nav"`, forgot to close class "

Comment: Why are you using JQuery, and still using `querySelector` and `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Zack I am clicking on the hamburger, I tested it with an alert and that does work, its just that It wont change it class. I tried to work witg classList togle quite some times but it just don't seem to work :/

Comment: @JohanStaart Hamburger? I dont' see any hamburger... All I see is a css comment referencing a hamburger...

Comment: @ JohanStaart, you have to let the screen size go below 480

Comment: @Zack I used the following code and it worked:


$(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
 
  alert("Hamburger works");

});

Comment: btw, in your example code, the media query says less than 400 px, not 480

Comment: @Toni Yes sorry, I meant 400, I will edit it

Comment: @LaSalazar, I changed it to jquery, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be:

```
$(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
  $(".navigation_menu").toggleClass("new");
});
```

Comment: It don't seem to work :/? What do you mean with "new" should I make it like .navigation_menu.new ?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest make a separate class for when it's activated. [here is an example of this that works](http://codepen.io/boltaway/pen/Eiqnf)

Comment: @Erik Ramirez It worked, I didnt use your &.active but just .active and that seemed to work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".Nav-Toggle").click(function(){
        jQuery(".navigation_menu").toggleClass("navigation_menu_new");
    });
});
```

Depending on what extra functionality you wish to achieve, you may want to explore using addClass/removeClass alternatively, but for the purposes of 'swapping' classes, toggleClass is all you need. Make sure to test it as I did in a smaller example so you do not have to overcomplicate yourself with the big picture: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m27oox4y/2/)

Comment: I modified it, give it a try

Comment: you're welcome, I just noticed that the first answer has the same answer I worked on, I should come back more regularly to check other people's answers.